How to take responce of radio button in listview and compare it with correct option
I am making one question answer app in that I have retrived all data from remote server using volley on the form of radion button in custom layout of listview, Now I want to take responce from user in the form of radio button and compare it with correct option and in the last I want to show total result in the form of toast message. Please help I am stuck here, I am new in android.enter image description here
Main Activity
public class ChemistryTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    public static ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<>(android.R.layout.activity_list_item);
    String url = "https:sample.php";

    Student student;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chemistry_test);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, studentArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        retrieveData();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     **//What need to write here**
            }
        });

       listView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {            
           }
       });
    }

    public void retrieveData() {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        studentArrayList.clear();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                            if (sucess.equals("1")) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = object.getString("id");
                                    String question = object.getString("question");
                                    String option1 = object.getString("option1");
                                    String option2 = object.getString("option2");
                                    String option3 = object.getString("option3");
                                    String option4 = object.getString("option4");
                                    String correct = object.getString("correct");
                         student = new Student(id, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, correct);
                                    studentArrayList.add(student);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ChemistryTestActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}

My Adapater class
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {

    Context context;
    List<Student> arrayListStudent;

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Student> arrayListStudent) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_list_item, arrayListStudent);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayListStudent = arrayListStudent;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null, true);

        TextView tvQuestionNo = view.findViewById(R.id.question_no);
        TextView tvQuestion = view.findViewById(R.id.question);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_question);
        RadioButton rbOption1 = view.findViewById(R.id.option1);
        RadioButton rbOption2 = view.findViewById(R.id.option2);
        RadioButton rbOption3 = view.findViewById(R.id.option3);
        RadioButton rbOption4 = view.findViewById(R.id.option4);
        RadioButton rbCorrect = view.findViewById(R.id.correct);

        tvQuestionNo.setText(arrayListStudent.get(position).getId());
        tvQuestion.setText("Q" + arrayListStudent.get(position).getQuestion());
        rbOption1.setText(arrayListStudent.get(position).getOption1());
        rbOption2.setText(arrayListStudent.get(position).getOption2());
        rbOption3.setText(arrayListStudent.get(position).getOption3());
        rbOption4.setText(arrayListStudent.get(position).getOption4());
        rbCorrect.setText(arrayListStudent.get(position).getCorrect() + " <-- Correct Ans");

        return view;
    }
}


